# How to migrate data from IBM blockchain to other hyperledger fabric cloud?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I have IBM blockchain infrastruture where I have all blockchain related data now I want to migrate whole data except user certs. to other hyperledger fabric infrastruture. so I want ledger and couchDB data with same transactionID and blocknumber. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be just to start a new Hyperledger Node/Network in another cloud, install chaincodes, add it to the desired channels and private data collections currently in IBM cloud. This way you'll get the full copy of your ledger and stateDB (CouchDB in your case).